# Choice of tables for a project to handle attendance

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on my students attendance system project. I have a list of students along with their ID (`jntuno`) and I need to create a database in MySQL for storing the daily attendance of each student for each subject.

**Table:** `students`

**Fields:**

```
slno int(5) auto increment,
jntuno char(15),
name char(50),
primary key(slno,jntuno).
```

**Data:**

[image: Data in students table]

This `students` table holds the list of students and their IDs.

Now I created another table:

**Table:** `dailyatt`

**Fields:**

```
date date,
subject char(10),
classesconducted int(2),
`11341A0501` int(2),
`11341A0502` int(2),
`11341A0503` int(2),
.
.
.
`11341A0537` int(2),
primary key(date,subject).
```

This table will look like:

> ```
> +------------+-----------+-----------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
> |date        |subject    |classesconducted |11341A0501  |11341A0502 |11341A0503 |....
> +------------+-----------+-----------------+------=-----+-----------+-----------+
> |            |           |                 |            |           |           |
> ```

Now every day upon entering the attendance on the PHP website, a new row will be created for each subject taught on that day.

But many said that the database model is not a good one. Can someone suggest a better model for this kind of problem?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Please use sensible names for your column names. Even though I read you explanation I can only vaguely guess what `slno` and `jntunno` might mean. I assume `jntunno` is some sort of student id (that's what I'm guessing from the `student` table - each student seems to have a unique one) - so what about `studentid`? I assume `slno` is simple primary id - so why no name it `id`?
2. Your `dailyatt` table has a column for each student (based on my assumptions above). I assume it is supposed to show which student has attended a specific class at a specific date. Now what happens if you add a new student - you will have to add a new column to your db schema, and another one, and another one ....

Furthermore the new students might not have been enrolled for older classes yet when you add a new column you have to choose a value for old attendances. So you start making special values for that case.

Also try creating a query like *How many students have attended a specific class*. It will end up looking like this `select 11341A0501+11341A0502+... from dailyatt where ...` - not very nice.

**In other words**: Yes, it's a bad idea for more than one reason.

When designing a schema and you try to think in terms of objects or concepts then a table should describe that object or concept - meaning the columns should be the properties of it and the rows should be the various instances of it. So I'd make three tables:

`courses` - describes courses (id, name, subject/description)

`classes` - describes classes (id, date and time, courseid) (so this table holds all the classes held for a specific course)

`classattendance` - student attendance for a specific class (id, classid, studentid)

Then you could do a `select count(*) as numStudentsAttended from classattendance where classid = 1234` to find how many student attended a specific class for example.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove all the `11341xxxx` fields.
2. Add another table consisting of the student-ID and the course-number (I suppose, those `11341A0501`) are course numbers.

To make it even better, introduce another table `Courses` with an ID (`autoinc`), the course-number (`11341A0501`) and -if you like- more information (name, description etc.)

Then, your `student-visits-course` table consists of two columns(`student-ID`, `course-ID`)

**Also**: Why is `slno,jntuno` a combined primary key? use the `slno` alone and create a separate index on the `jntuno` column to speeding up searching for a specific student by number.

Answer (score 1):

In your `students` table, `slno` is already `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so the intention is that `slno` should uniquely identify a student.  So why is `jntunno` also part of the primary key?  I think it should be

```
CREATE TABLE students
( slno int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, jntunno char(15) NOT NULL UNIQUE
, name char(50)
, UNIQUE KEY (jntunno)
);
```

By the way, `slno` and `jntunno` are programmer-unfriendly names.  Please pick something else.

`ALTER`ing the `dailyatt` table every time you add or remove a student is going to be a nightmare.  Database schema changes should be extremely rare events, because they are risky, hard to manage, and hurt performance while they happen.  Basically, it's wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE class_sessions
( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, date date
, subject char(10)
, classesconducted int(2)
, UNIQUE KEY (date, subject) -- Maybe?
);

CREATE TABLE attendance
( class_session_id INT NOT NULL
, student_id int(5)
, PRIMARY KEY (class_session_id, student_id)
, FOREIGN KEY (class_session_id) REFERENCES class_sessions(id)
, FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(slno)
);
```

If you want the data presented in one big table, with one column per student, you should leave it to your application-layer code or a [stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3516795/1157100) to compose the query.